# Custom Depth of Field in User Perspective view?

Tags: edit-mode, depth-of-field

Hello is it possible to set different Depth of Field when editing 3D model in Perspective view?
Not in rendering.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can turn it on in the Shading menu, but it works only through a camera.[image]

Comment: That is not what I need but it seems that Blender cannot do this.
But thanks anyway.